# Combining If condition and For loop in Table

Tags: graphics, list-manipulation

I want to generate a square matrix of squares with parallel lines/stripes colored with different colors:

```
columnNumber = 10;
rowNumber = 10;
icolumn = 1;

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black],
 Table[{
  If[(i == icolumn  || i == icolumn + 2 || i == icolumn + 4 ||
      i == icolumn + 6 || i == icolumn + 8),
   Blue,
   Green],
  Rectangle[{1.07*i, 1.07*j}]},
 {i, 1, columnNumber, 1.}, {j, 1, rowNumber, 1.}]},
AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 240]
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I substitute 
for the `If` condition,

```
(i == icolumn || i == icolumn+2 || i == icolumn+4 || i == icolumn+6 || i == icolumn+8)
```

the `For` loop

```
For[icol = 1, icol < 10, icol = icol + 2, If[i == icol, Blue, Green]]
```

like this:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black],
 Table[{
  For[icol = 1, icol < 10, icol = icol + 2,
   If[i == icol, Blue, Green]],
  Rectangle[{1.05*i, 1.05*j}]},
  {i, 1, columnNumber, 1}, {j, 1, rowNumber, 1}]},
 AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 240]
```

But then it returns a black image:

[image]

*Can anyone suggest what is wrong with my code that combines `For` and `If`?*

Comment: Why must you use `For[]`? In any event: `With[{rowNumber = 10, columnNumber = 10}, Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Table[{If[OddQ[i], Blue, Green], Rectangle[{1.07*i, 1.07*j}]}, {j, rowNumber}, {i, columnNumber}]}]]`

Comment: J.M. thanks for replying. I thought it is simpler to implement. Do you have other suggestion?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but I want to use differnt periods, not only 2. For instance any integer number: period=3, 4,...: icol=icol+m*period.

Comment: Then, use `Mod[]` or something.

Comment: @J.M, thanks. But, I want to generate binary (two-color) periodic strip pattern with certain period (stripPeriod) and strip width (stripWidth). For instance for 4-line strip pattern with period of 11 lines I apply one-by-one the conditions (Mod[i, stripPeriod] == 0) || (Mod[i + 1, stripPeriod] == 0) || (Mod[i + 2, stripPeriod] == 0) || (Mod[i + 3, stripPeriod] == 0).

Comment: `@J.M` Since the strips will also be tilted, believe the best way would defining condition separately and then apply to generate Table, Matrix, Array or Grid. Is there any to realize it?

Comment: The short answer is that `For` returns the value `Null` always, so your colors are not being passed up to the graphics.  You certainly want to be using `Table` instead, just like in your first code.

Answer (score 3):

Try this for a start:

```
    lst = Table["", {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}];
lst1 = Flatten[Table[{{{1, 10}, {i, i}} -> Blue}, {i, 1, 10, 2}], 1];
lst2 = Flatten[Table[{{{1, 10}, {i, i}} -> Green}, {i, 2, 10, 2}], 1];
lst3 = Join[{None, None}, {Join[lst1, lst2]}];

Grid[lst, Dividers -> Directive[White, AbsoluteThickness[0.3]], 
 Background -> lst3, ItemSize -> {2, 2}]
```

returning this:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexei Boulbitch !!!

Comment: `@Alexei Boulbitch`. Thanks!!! it is a nice solution for my initial question. But, in general I want to generate binary (two-color) periodic strip pattern with certain period (`stripPeriod`) and strip width (`stripWidth`). For instance for 4-line strip pattern with period of 11 lines I have to apply one-by-one the conditions `(Mod[i, stripPeriod] == 0) || (Mod[i + 1, stripPeriod] == 0) || (Mod[i + 2, stripPeriod] == 0) || (Mod[i + 3, stripPeriod] == 0)`.

Comment: `@Alexei Boulbitch`. If I need strips with many lines, then I have to enter all the conditions one-by-one, which is kind of annoying. I am trying to get “condition generation” or in other words “strip generation” using `stripWidth` parameter in any kind of loop, but it does not work properly. Since the strips will also be tilted, I believe the best way would defining `condition` separately and then apply to generate Table, Matrix, Array or Grid. Is there any way to realize it?

Comment: @surfAliq That's what I have shown you. The formation of stripes is fixed by the list `lst3`. Now it is constructed of two sublists: `lst1` giving the blue squares and `lst2` giving the green ones.  Check, how they are organized. If you need more stripes, make more such lists, and, of course, reorganize them correspondingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array` pretty much anywhere you can use `Table`, and when the input is naturally thought of as a function, it is more natural to use `Array`.  In this case the function is

```
f = Function[{i, j}, {If[OddQ[i], Blue, Green], Rectangle[{1.05*i, 1.05*j}]}]
```

You can then create the 2d list of rectangles

```
arr = Array[f, {10, 10}];
```

and make your graphic:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], arr}]
```

Naturally you could also use this function with `Table`, but it is more verbose:

```
arr2 = Table[f[i, j], {i, 10}, {j, 10}];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], arr2}]
```

**Edit:**

Finally, as suggested by bill_s, you might find `ArrayPlot` adequate to your needs:

```
f3 = Function[{i, j}, If[OddQ[j], 0, 1]];
arr3 = Array[f3, {10, 10}]
ArrayPlot[arr3, ColorRules -> {0 -> Blue, 1 -> Green}, Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Black]
```

However, the display is a bit different, and you won't have direct access to your array of rectangles.

**Edit:**

You can change the function however you wish.  E.g., To change the width of the strips to 4, just change the `f3` to `f4`:

```
f4 = Function[{i, j}, If[EvenQ@Floor[(j - 1)/4], 0, 1]]
```

Comment: much better, Thanks!

Comment: @surfAliq http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Alan. Thanks!!! it is a nice solution for my initial question. But, in general I want to generate binary (two-color) periodic strip pattern with certain period (`stripPeriod`) and strip width (`stripWidth`). For instance for 4-line strip pattern with period of 11 lines I have to apply one-by-one the conditions `(Mod[i, stripPeriod] == 0) || (Mod[i + 1, stripPeriod] == 0) || (Mod[i + 2, stripPeriod] == 0) || (Mod[i + 3, stripPeriod] == 0)`.

Comment: @Alan. If I need strips with many lines, then I have to enter all the conditions one-by-one, which is kind of annoying. I am trying to get “condition generation” or in other words “strip generation” using `stripWidth` parameter in any kind of loop, but it does not work properly. Since the strips will also be tilted, I believe the best way would defining `condition` separately and then apply to generate Table, Matrix, Array or Grid. Is there any way to realize it?

Comment: @surfAliq See edit.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned wanting to do it for multiple patterns. Here is a 3-stripe version:

```
ArrayPlot[ConstantArray[Mod[Range[10], 3], 10],ColorFunction->"Rainbow", Mesh->True]
```

[image]

Change the Mod (change the 3) for a different number of stripes, the colorspace for the coloring, and the size of the array (change the 10) to achieve what you want.

If you want to specify an arbitrary pattern of columns, one approach is to do it with a simple list: for instance a two color pattern with 11 element might be:

```
pat = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1};
ArrayPlot[ConstantArray[pat, 10], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> True]
```

[image]

Of course, you can generate the `pat` in many ways, depending on the exact pattern you want.

Comment: `b@bill s` Thanks!!! it is a nice solution for my initial question. But, I in general I want to generate binary (two-color) periodic strip pattern with certain period (stripPeriod) and strip width (stripWidth). 
For instance for 4-line strip pattern with period of 11 lines I have to apply one-by-one the conditions `(Mod[i, stripPeriod] == 0) || (Mod[i + 1, stripPeriod] == 0) || (Mod[i + 2, stripPeriod] == 0) || (Mod[i + 3, stripPeriod] == 0)`.

Comment: If I need strips with many lines, then I have to enter all the conditions one-by-one, which is kind of annoying. I am trying to get “condition generation” or in other words “strip generation” using `stripWidth` parameter in any kind of loop, but it does not work properly.
Since the strips will also be tilted, I believe the best way would defining `condition` separately and then apply to generate Table, Matrix, Array or Grid. Is there any way to realize it?

Answer (score 3):

In:

```
matrixPlot[xs_] := 
 MatrixPlot[xs, ColorRules -> {0 -> Green, 1 -> Blue}, Mesh -> All ]
matrixPlot@Array[Mod[#2, 2] &, {10, 10}]
```

Out:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(Using ColorRules instead of ColorFunction, Thanks to J. M.)

Comment: `ColorRules` seems to be the more appropriate option here: `MatrixPlot[Array[Mod[#2, 2] &, {10, 10}], ColorRules -> {1 -> Green, 0 -> Blue}, Mesh -> All]`

Answer (score 2):

I made some changes to YOUR code

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], 
Table[{If[EvenQ@i, Green, Blue], Rectangle[{1.05*i, 1.05*j}]}, {i, 
columnNumber}, {j, rowNumber}]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
ImageSize -> 240]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear ALL (J.M., Alexei Boulbitch, bill s, Alan, Jenny_mathy, UnchartedWorks)

Many THANKS for your helps-suggestions!!!!!!!!
They all are nice solution for my initial question. But, I want to generate binary (two-color) periodic strip pattern with certain period (stripPeriod) and strip width (stripWidth). 
For instance here I generate 4-line strip pattern with period of 11 lines by applying one-by-one the conditions (Mod[i, stripPeriod] == 0) || (Mod[i + 1, stripPeriod] == 0) || (Mod[i + 2, stripPeriod] == 0) || (Mod[i + 3, stripPeriod] == 0).

Comment: But if I need strips with many lines, then I have to enter all the conditions one-by-one, which kind of annoying. I am trying to get “condition generation” or in other words “strip generation” using stripWidth in loops, but it does not work properly.
Since the strips will also be tilted, believe the best way would defining condition separately and then apply to generate Table, Matrix or Array.

Comment: columnNumber = 40;
rowNumber = 15;
stripPeriod = 11;
stripWidth = 3;(*I want to use this parameter in condition*)


Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], 
  Table[{If [(Mod[i, stripPeriod] == 0) || (Mod[i + 1, stripPeriod] ==
         0) || (Mod[i + 2, stripPeriod] == 
        0) || (Mod[i + 3, stripPeriod] == 0), Blue, Green], 
    Rectangle[{1.07*i, 1.07*j}]}, {i, 1, columnNumber, 1.}, {j, 1, 
    rowNumber, 1.}]}, AspectRatio -> rowNumber/columnNumber, 
 ImageSize -> 500]

Answer (score 1):

If you're contemplating complicated coloring patterns, as seems to be the case in the comments, I would suggest creating a function to compute the color of the `i,j` rectangle.

```
colorfn[i_, j_] := < your code here >;

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black],
 Table[{
  colorfn[i, j],
  Rectangle[{1.07*i, 1.07*j}]},
 {i, 1, columnNumber, 1.}, {j, 1, rowNumber, 1.}]},
AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 240]
```

For example,
the following, with an extra error check, reproduces the OP's figure:

```
colorfn[i_, j_] :=
  If[(i == icolumn  || i == icolumn + 2 || i == icolumn + 4 ||
      i == icolumn + 6 || i == icolumn + 8),
   Blue,
   Green,
   Red];  (* should not happen; if Red shows up, there's a coding error somewhere *)
```

See [`If`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) for an explanation of the fourth argument.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Still inside `If` I have to add all the conditions one-by-one, whereas I wanted to do it with `For`, but it turns out `For` is not the best option.

Comment: @surfAliq You're welcome. (1) No one who knows *Mathematica* wants to use `For` :) -- there are usually better alternatives. (2) You have to write the `colorfn[]` code the way you want; I just used your code as an example of how to use a `colorfn`. J.M. showed you a way to avoid the conditions one-by-one (usuing `OddQ[]` or `Mod[]`), but it's hard to show a generic way except in a particular example. E.g `{Red, Green, Blue}[[ Mod[i, 3, 1] ]]` will cycle through the three colors. Or more generally `colorlist[[ Mod[i, Length@colorlist, 1] ]]`, where `colorlist` is a list of colors, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got four solutions: via `ArrayPlot`, `Graphics`, `MatrixPlot`, and `Grid`.

```
columns = 70; (*column numbers*)
rows = 20; (*row numbers*)
j0 = 1; (*first column*)
period = 8;(*period*)
strip = 3; (*strip width*)
```

Solution with `ArrayPlot`:

```
Manipulate[
fStrips = Function[{i, j}, If[Floor[Mod[((j - j0) + period), period], strip] == strip, 
1(*Even numbers*), 0(*Odd numbers*)]];
arrStrips = Array[fStrips, {rows, columns}];
ArrayPlot[arrStrips, ColorRules -> {1 -> Blue, 0 -> Green}, Mesh -> True,   MeshStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> 700], {j0, 1, 10, 
1}, {strip, 1, 6, 1}, {period, 3, 20, 1}]
```

Solutionwith `Graphics`:

```
Manipulate[
colorfn[i_, j_] := If[Floor[Mod[((i - j0) + period), period], strip] == strip, Blue, Green];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], 
Table[{colorfn[i, j], Rectangle[{1.05*i, 1.05*j}]}, {i, 1, columns,
  1}, {j, 1, rows, 1}]}, AspectRatio -> rows/columns, 
ImageSize -> 700], {j0, 1, 10, 1}, {strip, 1, 6, 1}, {period, 3, 20,1}]
```

[image]

Solution with `MatrixPlot`:

```
Manipulate[
matrixPlot[xs_] := MatrixPlot[xs, ColorRules -> {0 -> Blue, 1 -> Green, 2 -> Green}, Mesh -> All, AspectRatio -> rows/columns];
matrixPlot@
Array[If[Floor[Mod[(((#2 - j0) - j0) + period), period], strip] == 
  strip, 0, 1] &, {rows, columns}], {j0, 1, 10, 1}, {strip, 1, 6, 1}, {period, 3, 20, 1}]
```

[image]

Solution with `Grid`:

```
tableSize = 30;
j0 = 1; (*first column*)
period = 5;(*period*)
strip = 3; (*strip width: used via lstStrip[1], lstStrip[2], and lstStrip[3]*)

lst = Table["", {i, 1, tableSize}, {j, 1, tableSize}];
lst0 = Flatten[Table[{{{1, tableSize}, {i, i}} -> Green}, {i, 1, tableSize, 1}], 1];
lstStrip[veticalLine_] := Flatten[Table[{{{1, tableSize}, {i, i}} -> Blue}, {i, -j0 + veticalLine, tableSize, period}], 1];

lstFinal = Join[{None, 
None}, {Join[lst0, lstStrip[1], lstStrip[2], lstStrip[3]]}];
Grid[lst, Dividers -> Directive[White, AbsoluteThickness[0.3]], Background -> lstFinal, ItemSize -> {2, 2}]
```

[image]

Thanks!!!